# Finding the volume of the area under a parabola about the x-axis?

Tags: integration, volume

I'm having trouble with this question:

"Find the area bounded by the parabola $y=2x-x^2$, the y-axis and the line y=1 is rotated about the x-axis. Find the volume"

I assume we start off by finding the value of $y^2$, which is $(2x-x^2)^2$, then the bounds (which are found by substituting y=1, and the y-axis which is x=0). The bounds, I think, are x=1 and x=0.

You then find the integral, and multiply it by pi.

Is what I'm doing right?

Thanks

Comment: Just be careful! The volume you are looking for is not the volume over which you are integrating. You want to subtract the value you get from the volume of the cylinder which is $\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right you are!

(See the nice graph created by Wolfram Alpha, below.)

[image]

So assuming we are seeking the volume of the region between the parabola and the x-axis, rotated about the x-axis, we have the following integral:

$$V = \int_0^1 \pi\Big((2x-x^2)^2 - 0\Big)\,dx = \pi \int_0^1  (4x^2 - 4x^3 + x^4)\,dx$$

On the other hand, if we are interested in the region between the line $y = 1$ and the parabola rotated about the x-axis, then we have the following integral:

$$V = \int_0^1 \pi\Big(1- (2x-x^2)^2\Big)\,dx = \pi \int_0^1  (1-4x^2 + 4x^3 - x^4)\,dx$$

Comment: Also needs a TU! +1

Comment: @amWhy, the integral should be from $0$ to $1$ for the question asked; this forms a clsoed region. By symmetry about $x=1$, the total volume should be half of what you calculate.